# Navigation Controller with Tab Bar only on first view

Tags: iphone

I am seeking advice on how to start my project.

I need to use a combination of the navigation controller and tabbar controller but on the second screen, I need the tabbar controller not to be there. Here is a brief description of the two main screens

Screen 1 will have a tabbar controller with two tabs. The first tab is a tableview and when you tap on a table cell, it drills down to Screen 2. The second tab is just a filter view that updates the table in the first tab of Screen 1.

Screen two is just a details screen from the cells of Screen 1. The catch is that I don't want the TabBar on Screen 2.

I am struggling with how to get started.

Do I start with a Navigation-based application since I need to be able to drill down?  How do I just add a tab bar to the main screen of the navigation based app?

I can't start with a Tab Bar application because if I load a navigation controller inside one of the views of the tab controller, then when I drill down inside the nav controller, the tab bar still stays on the next screen when I need it to go away.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the tab bar once the 2nd view gets pushed.  You can hide it in the `viewDidAppear` method and animate it so that it looks fluid.

The navigation controller has a property that will do the work for you (put this just before you call the nav controller to push the new view):

```
navigationControllerNameHere.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

or

```
- (void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated { 
 self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; 
}
```